# View large data set on the R console

Tags: r, dataset

Is there any way to view a large data set [1380160 obs. of 44 variables] in full on the R console ?

I have changed the print limit using `options(max.print=...)`, however, I cannot see the full data set, i.e. right from the first row to the last as there is no way to scroll through the data.

Comment: Can saving to a csv and opening with a spreadsheet program work for you? That is what I usually do.

Comment: Saving this much data takes my computer more than 30 seconds and opening in excel took 45 seconds. I tried with `View()` and it took more than 6 minutes to open. It opened in `fix()` and `edit()`in about a minute.

Comment: Final comment from me, if it isn't obvious at this point, I am not sure you want to view the whole thing. Just view sections or samples from your data.

Comment: It's not obvious to *me* what you are going to see when you look at this data set (1.4 million observations) ... ?  Paul Murrell wrote a neat "rdataviewer" package (see http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/Talks/viewer.pdf ) that seems particularly useful for viewing large data sets, but I'm not sure if it's still functional/available -- I don't think it ever got very much past the proof-of-concept stage ...

Comment: Cheers. I know it's not feasible to view the whole data set, but I wanted to find out if there is a way to do this (just in case) I want to eyeball through the whole data.

Comment: Any update on new methods for viewing large datasets? Still curious, as this is the only thing Excel still has value for..

Answer (score 8):

Use the `View` function (note the capitol 'V'), it will open a data frame, matrix, or other table like object in a new window in a spreadsheet style format that can be scrolled for viewing the data (but not editing).  This window is independent of the console so you can continue to issue commands without having to close the viewing window (however changes to the data object will not be seend in the viewing window, you will need to close the window and run `View` again to see the changes).

If you want to edit the data in a spreadsheet like window then use `edit` or `fix` (but with these you cannot run other commands until you close the editing window).

Some of the GUI's for R also have tools for viewing or editing data objects with scrolling.

Comment: Thank you. I am going to try this soon :)

Answer (score 6):

Two choices:

```
df <- data.frame(X = rpois(n = 100, lambda = 3), Y = rnorm(n = 100, mean = 25, sd = 7))
page(x = df, method = "print")
View(x = df , title = "My test data")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, however, I was having the same problem.
I find the `View data set` in Rcmdr quite good for viewing big data sets. It shows all the data (in a window however).

```
library(relimp, pos=35)
showData(Dat, placement='-20+200', font=getRcmdr('logFont'), maxwidth=80,  maxheight=10)
```